# How to import API based component in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created Api.jsx file in side of API calling, if I checked http://localhost:3000/Api data is coming, but I want to call Api.jsx file import to index.js file but data is don't come, what am missing could you please let me know.

Api.jsx

```
function Api({ stars }) {
  return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div>
}

Api.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
  const json = await res.json()
  return { stars: json.stargazers_count }
}

export default Api
```

index.js

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
// import Head from 'next/head'
// import Image from 'next/image' 
// import Blog from '../comps/Blog'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
const ApiComponent= dynamic(() => import('./comps/Api'));

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <p>Welcome</p>
      <ApiComponent/>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <a
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{' '}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </footer> */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Data fetching methods like `getInitialProps`/`getStaticProps` only work on page components. It can't be used on regular components that you import. You'll need to either fetch the data at the page level and pass it to the component, OR fetch the data in the component client-side.

Comment: Could you please reference or solve this issue please

Comment: Maybe [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) can help you.

Comment: Can you please add example code

Comment: could please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374392/refresh-issue-in-nextjs-page